# How can I pick a random user from a server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I tried making a bot command that replies with "(random user) is bot". I tried other solutions, but they didn't work. Here's my code:

```
if (msg.content === 'wb!bot') {
        let userArray = Array.from(msg.member.guild.members);
        let randomUser = userArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * msg.guild.memberCount)];

        console.log(randomUser);
        console.log(userArray);

        msg.channel.send(randomUser + ' is bot');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using math.random is pointless when the `Collection` class already has a `.random()` method

```js
//msg.guild.members.cache if v12
const usersCollection = msg.guild.members;
const randomUser = usersCollection.random();
```

Comment: It says TypeError: usersCollection.random is not a function now.

Comment: what version are you on? If it's v12 change usersCollection to `msg.guild.members.cache`

Answer (score 0):

Your use of `Math.random` is incorrect.

```js
// Generate the array for the snippet
const userArray = [];

for (let i = 0 ; i < 100 ; ++i) {
  userArray.push(`user${i + 1}`);
}

// Function that returns you a random number
// https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_random.asp
function getRndInteger(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) ) + min;
}

// Pick a random user
const user = userArray[getRndInteger(0, userArray.length)];

// Display it
console.log(`${user} is bot`);
```

Comment: Now instead of using usernames it says user(random number). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: please edit your question and add the new code you have. It's hard for me to detect the error you have now.

Comment: @Warrior You need to use the array of users instead of the random user array they generated for the snippet.